How do I modify a CRD's `group:` so I can avoid this error from Kubernetes API server: `Error from server (NotFound): [...]`
When I apply a CRD defined as
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: somethings.some.group.io
spec:
  group: some.group.io

[...]

then I query the API server to check the CRD has been installed
$ kubectl get somethings
No resources found in default namespace.

and then remove the CRD and reapply modified CRD with a different group
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: somethings.something.different.some.group.io
spec:
  group: something.different.some.group.io

[...]

I now get an error from kubectl
$ kubectl get somethings
Error from server (NotFound): Unable to list "some.group.io/v1, Resource=somethings": the server could not find the requested resource (get somethings.some.group.io)

What's happening?
Initial investigation
Turns out, that after i run kubectl with the full new of the resource, that is, kubectl get somethings.different.some.group.io, the short name kubectl get somethings will start working again.
Reproduction script
Here are reproduction steps with a sample CRD for kind something:
function apply_crd {
  local group=$1
  kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: somethings.${group}
spec:
  group: ${group}
  names:
    kind: Something
    listKind: SomethingList
    singular: something
    plural: somethings
  scope: Namespaced
  versions:
    - name: v1
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true
      served: true
      storage: true  
EOF
}

# create it with some.group.io and query it
apply_crd "some.group.io"
kubectl get somethings

# delete it, recreate under different group, and immediately query again
kubectl delete CustomResourceDefinition/somethings.some.group.io
apply_crd "different.some.group.io"
kubectl get somethings

This produces
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io "somethings.some.group.io" deleted
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/somethings.different.some.group.io created
Error from server (NotFound): Unable to list "some.group.io/v1, Resource=somethings": the server could not find the requested resource (get somethings.some.group.io)

Now run the kubectl get with the full name of the resource, this busts some caches somewhere (?), and then the short name also starts working
$ kubectl get somethings.different.some.group.io
No resources found in default namespace.

$ kubectl get somethings
No resources found in default namespace.

